# using azure cosmos mongodb inside kubernetes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure, kubernetes, azure-cosmosdb

I have a nodeJS api which uses a mongoDb. I deploy the application in a kubernetes cluster. 
Here you can find the kubernetes yml files https://github.com/daumann/chronas-api/tree/azure/kuberneties

Now I want to use the azure cosmosdb for mongodb instatt of an container. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-introduction

Can someone help me how I can do that. 
It would be create to use only the yml files from kuberneties to do so.

Cheers

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Cosmos DB isn't something you can install like native MongoDB; it's a service. Meaning... just a connection string (and creating an instance of a database within the service, of course). What, exactly, are you having difficulty with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already launched your cosmos-db through Azure, you will need to use the generated connection string that you can pass to your application as a secret (since it contains a password). The connection string is of the format:

```
mongodb://username:password@host:port/[database]?ssl=true
```

To create a secret (assuming you paste your connection string into the `connstring.txt` file:

```
kubectl create secret generic cosmos-db-secret --from-file=./connstring.txt
```

Then in your application's deployment definition add:

```
env:
  - name: MONGO_HOST
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: cosmos-db-secret
        key: connstring
```

Comment: great thanks for the answer! is there as well a possibility via service catalog from kubernetes